# Border with a chamfered corner in xaml

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I need to create a border with a chamfered corner.

CornerRadius only creates rounded corners. Is there some additional attribute I could apply to make it an angle?

```
<Border BorderBrush="Cyan" CornerRadius="0,0,45,0" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Cyan" Margin="20"/>   
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use an adorner for a customized border. Create an adorner class that implements the OnRender to draw the chamfered corner. Then attach the adorner to the ellipse's adorner layer.

```
layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(myEllipse)
layer.Add(New ChamferedAdorner(myEllipse))
```